# Why was my flag disputed even though the flagged answer got deleted?

Tags: support, flags, not-an-answer, disputed-flags

Couple days ago I have flagged a very obvious not-an-answer post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18015873/modelmetadata-additional-values-always-empty-mvc4/20910795#20910795) where user [GunMetalBlue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1779486/gunmetalblue) has blindly copy-pasted another answer and typed a "thank you!" response to that below. This answer was removed soon after being flagged (and due to my low reputation I cannot view it anymore), however, I got a disputed flag status. Is there any reason why?

Here is a screenshot from Wayback Machine:
[image]

Comment: I was one of the reviewers that disputed your flag, in review we can not see the other answers (we only see the answer you have flagged and if there are some comments under it), however the last phrase *"Works for me!, Thank you"*, should have made me investigate more. A good way to help the reviewers is also to leave a comment under the answer explaining what is wrong, anyway mea culpa, sorry.

Comment: @PetterFriberg Thank you very much for your clarification, I will certainly do that next time. Unfortunately, I had assumed all flags are being processed by Moderators who have full access to the thread, and omitted any comments that I could have added otherwise. My bad!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your flag was disputed because 3 people voted to keep it alive by choosing "Looks OK" in the [low quality review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/16669343).

The post was deleted because it was later custom flagged as

> This is not an answer. This is a thank-you to another answer posted earlier on the same question. stackoverflow.com/a/18018083 Everything except the last sentence is a copy of the another answer. The last sentence is a thank-you. Please delete this post.

(seeing which I deleted the post).

Henceforth, if you find any answer, which is not clear enough to be detected as a NAA from the queue, use a custom flag.

Comment: Oh, and btw, reviewers were given proper guidance (or so I hope D:)

Answer (score 4):

If I had to guess, it was probably disputed because it wasn't obvious to the reviewers (to be clear, not moderators) that this was a thank-you answer. After all, it does look more like a copy of the other answer than a thank-you answer. (What's funny is that it *was* more obviously so in its original state with the misplaced quote markup, which was then mistakenly removed by an editor a few years ago. A perfect example of well-intentioned edits actually muddying the intended meaning of a post...)

Another user raised a custom flag in case it was in fact not all that obvious, and that is what prompted a moderator to delete the answer. The moderator was not involved in your NAA flag at all.